# Programmatically setting property values in a usercontrol in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am programatically creating instance of usercontrol as shown below

```
   Dim uc As Control
                uc = Me.LoadControl("~/Controls/DigitalSign.ascx")
                Me.Controls.Add(uc)
```

I have two public properties in my usercontorl like clerkName and RespName. How can I set those values in the above code. Intellisense is not showing ClerkName and respName Properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should work

```
            Dim uc As DigitalSign
            uc = CType(Me.LoadControl("~/Controls/DigitalSign.ascx"), DigitalSign)
            Me.Controls.Add(uc)
```

Comment: Meaning... if you want Intellisense you need to use the type of YOUR usercontrol, not Control.  +1